# error while processing warehousecontrolwebservice using TFS web URL (TFS-2018)

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, olap-cube, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

i am getting below error when invoking GetProcessingStatus, any help to get this working will be appreciated

Actually we never used TFS analysis for providing reports, now i am trying to exploring  that options too.
I used below url to process the cube of analysis services

URL : http://localhost:8080/tfs/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/WarehouseControlService.asmx
[image: IMG 1]
After browsing that url we get below services

BringAnalysisProcessingOnline,
BringWarehouseProcessingOnline,
ChangeSetting,
GetJobProperties,
GetProcessingStatus,
GetSettings,
ProcessAnalysisDatabase,
ProcessDimensionForExpandedCapacity,
ProcessWarehouse,
SetAnalysisJobEnabledState,
SetWarehouseJobEnabledState,
TakeAnalysisProcessingOffline,
TakeWarehouseProcessingOffline,

Selecting "GetProcessingStatus" and invoking it with includeOnlineHostsOnly = True

[image: IMG 2]

Reporting configuration on TFS Console

[image: configuration of Reporting services]

Error

> [Full Analysis Database Sync]: --->
>   AnalysisDatabaseProcessingType=Full, needCubeSchemaUpdate=True. --->
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseException: TF221122: An
>   error occurred running job Full Analysis Database Sync for team
>   project collection or Team Foundation server TEAM FOUNDATION. --->
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseException: Failed to
>   Process Analysis Database 'Tfs_Analysis'. --->
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseException: Internal error:
>   The operation terminated unsuccessfully. Errors in the high-level
>   relational engine. . The exception was raised by the IDbConnection
>   interface. Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection
>   could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of
>   'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource', Name of 'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource'. Errors in
>   the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with
>   the ID of 'Dim Changeset', Name of 'Version Control Changeset' was
>   being processed. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred
>   while the 'Changeset Title' attribute of the 'Version Control
>   Changeset' dimension from the 'Tfs_Analysis' database was being
>   processed. Server: The current operation was cancelled because another
>   operation in the transaction failed. Errors in the high-level
>   relational engine. . The exception was raised by the IDbConnection
>   interface. Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection
>   could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of
>   'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource', Name of 'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource'. Errors in
>   the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with
>   the ID of 'Assembly', Name of 'Assembly' was being processed. Errors
>   in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Assembly'
>   attribute of the 'Assembly' dimension from the 'Tfs_Analysis' database
>   was being processed. Errors in the high-level relational engine. . The
>   exception was raised by the IDbConnection interface. Errors in the
>   high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the
>   data source with the DataSourceID of 'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource', Name of
>   'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource'. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error
>   occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Dim Changeset', Name of
>   'Version Control Changeset' was being processed. Errors in the OLAP
>   storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Changeset ID' attribute
>   of the 'Version Control Changeset' dimension from the 'Tfs_Analysis'
>   database was being processed. Errors in the high-level relational
>   engine. . The exception was raised by the IDbConnection interface.
>   Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be
>   made to the data source with the DataSourceID of
>   'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource', Name of 'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource'. Errors in
>   the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with
>   the ID of 'Dim Changeset', Name of 'Version Control Changeset' was
>   being processed. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred
>   while the 'Checked In By' attribute of the 'Version Control Changeset'
>   dimension from the 'Tfs_Analysis' database was being processed. Errors
>   in the high-level relational engine. . The exception was raised by the
>   IDbConnection interface. Errors in the high-level relational engine. A
>   connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID
>   of 'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource', Name of 'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource'. Errors
>   in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension,
>   with the ID of 'Dim Changeset', Name of 'Version Control Changeset'
>   was being processed. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error
>   occurred while the 'Policy Override Comment' attribute of the 'Version
>   Control Changeset' dimension from the 'Tfs_Analysis' database was
>   being processed. Warning: Parser: Out of line object 'Binding',
>   referring to ID(s) 'Tfs_Analysis, Team System, FactCurrentWorkItem',
>   has been specified but has not been used. Warning: Parser: Out of line
>   object 'Binding', referring to ID(s) 'Tfs_Analysis, Team System,
>   FactWorkItemHistory', has been specified but has not been used.
>   Warning: Parser: Out of line object 'Binding', referring to ID(s)
>   'Tfs_Analysis, Team System, v Fact WorkItem To Tree', has been
>   specified but has not been used. Warning: Parser: Out of line object
>   'Binding', referring to ID(s) 'Tfs_Analysis, Team System, v Fact
>   Linked Current WorkItem', has been specified but has not been used.
>   Warning: Parser: Out of line object 'Binding', referring to ID(s)
>   'Tfs_Analysis, Team System, Fact WorkItem To Category', has been
>   specified but has not been used. Warning: Parser: Out of line object
>   'Binding', referring to ID(s) 'Tfs_Analysis, Team System, v Fact
>   WorkItem Changeset', has been specified but has not been used.
>   Warning: Parser: Out of line object 'Binding', referring to ID(s)
>   'Tfs_Analysis, Team System, Fact Build Project', has been specified
>   but has not been used. Warning: Parser: Out of line object 'Binding',
>   referring to ID(s) 'Tfs_Analysis, Team System, Fact Build Details',
>   has been specified but has not been used. Warning: Parser: Out of line
>   object 'Binding', referring to ID(s) 'Tfs_Analysis, Team System, Fact
>   Code Churn', has been specified but has not been used. Warning:
>   Parser: Out of line object 'Binding', referring to ID(s)
>   'Tfs_Analysis, Team System, v Fact Test Result Overlay', has been
>   specified but has not been used. Warning: Parser: Out of line object
>   'Binding', referring to ID(s) 'Tfs_Analysis, Team System, Fact Build
>   Changeset', has been specified but has not been used. Warning: Parser:
>   Out of line object 'Binding', referring to ID(s) 'Tfs_Analysis, Team
>   System, Fact Build Coverage', has been specified but has not been
>   used. Warning: Parser: Out of line object 'Binding', referring to
>   ID(s) 'Tfs_Analysis, Team System, v Fact WorkItem Test Result', has
>   been specified but has not been used. Warning: Parser: Out of line
>   object 'Binding', referring to ID(s) 'Tfs_Analysis, Team System, v
>   Fact Linked Current Work Item Test Case', has been specified but has
>   not been used. Warning: Parser: Out of line object 'Binding',
>   referring to ID(s) 'Tfs_Analysis, Team System, Fact Run Coverage', has
>   been specified but has not been used. at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.TFSOlapProcessComponent.ExecuteXmla(String
>   finalXmla) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.TFSOlapProcessComponent.ProcessOlap(AnalysisDatabaseProcessingType
>   processingType, WarehouseChanges warehouseChanges, Boolean
>   lastProcessingFailed, Boolean cubeSchemaUpdateNeeded) --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace --- at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.TFSOlapProcessComponent.ProcessOlap(AnalysisDatabaseProcessingType
>   processingType, WarehouseChanges warehouseChanges, Boolean
>   lastProcessingFailed, Boolean cubeSchemaUpdateNeeded) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.AnalysisDatabaseSyncJobExtension.RunInternalCore(IVssRequestContext
>   requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime
>   queueTime, String& resultMessage) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.AnalysisDatabaseSyncJobExtension.RunInternal(IVssRequestContext
>   requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime
>   queueTime, String& resultMessage) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseJobExtension.RunCore(IVssRequestContext
>   requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime
>   queueTime, String& resultMessage) --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace ---

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the link to the datawarehouse.
Is the datawarehouse OK?

1. Connect to the data analysis server.
2. Go to the data source of Tfs_AnalysisServices and open properties.
3. Check the connection string, check if the connection string is OK.

If the connection string is not OK, fix it on the TFS Console. If the link is OK, maybe there is some problem in the datawarehouse, and you need to rebuild it too.

Comment: have you checked the connection to the datawarehouse? its everything ok then?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

You should run the **ProcessDimensionsForExpandedCapacity** web service when you receive one of the following error messages:... For Version Control. Check if this do the trick.

More details please refer this link-- [Process dimensions for expanded capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/admin/manually-process-data-warehouse-and-cube?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=dim-file#process-dimensions-for-expanded-capacity)

Besides, you should also check TFS Server Event View and go through if there is some useful information to help you narrow down the issue.

---

> TF221122: An error occurred running job Full Analysis Database Sync
>   for team project collection or Team Foundation server TEAM FOUNDATION.
>   --->

According to the detail error info in your shared log part. I would suggest you first check if the account you used the data source TFS_ASDataSource has bad or expired password or that the account does not exist anymore.

If this is a new deployment it might also be possible that the account does not have access to the TFS_Warehouse database or Tfs_Analysis database or it is not a member of the tfswarehousedatareader role.

To better troubleshoot is to update account used to access the data sources in the Team Foundation Server Administration Console in the Reporting page.

[image]

Or you could directly use workaround deleted the whole Analysis Database, and run the “**Rebuild**” operation from the Application Tier following the steps below:

1. Open Team Foundation Server Administration console.
2. Go to Reporting and there is “Start Rebuild”.

Note that this action could be used to rebuild your data warehouse and analysis database for the cube. Once you start it, it will take offline, delete, and rebuild both your Warehouse and Analysis Services databases. Based on the amount of data you have in your TFS DB, it could take significant amount of time to complete these jobs. The reports will not show any data until the above databases are not rebuilt successfully. This may do the trick.

Comment: tried this but the out come is same, any other solution please

Comment: Hi @KapilGupta If so, could you explain more clearly about your issue, better to include a detail description how you get stuck in this situation. And you could also update  some related screenshots in your original question.

Comment: thanks for your efforts, i have added more details with screenshot hope that will clear things alot.

Comment: Hi Kapil Gupta, thanks for your shared detail screenshot. Please give a try with the solution in my update reply.